# How to identify cause of large buffer memory usage?

Tags: linux, centos, memory, buffer

I have a production machine running a 2.6 kernel (Centos 6.7) with 64 GB of RAM of which 18 GB is apparently used for buffer memory.

I am interested in identifying specifically what that 18 GB is being used for so I can tell whether it is pathological or not.

This machine is a busy front-end load balancer + web server so it has a good deal of incoming as well as internal TCP connections. It does a fair bit of small disk I/Os randomly into a large (10's of millions of files) directory tree. It also writes a lot of data to web server log files, maybe a few 10's of GB per day.

I have tried using `slabtop` but the size of the slabs only seems to account for a portion of this usage (about 8 or 9 GB at the time of this writing.)

Is there any way to get a clearer picture of what constitutes the 18 GB so I can tell whether this is reasonable or not?

Here are some basic diagnostics:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux [HOSTNAME REMOVED] 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 19:59:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64377      64099        278         49      17935      34717
-/+ buffers/cache:      11446      52931
Swap:        32767        980      31787
```

`/proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:       65922808 kB
MemFree:          257868 kB
Buffers:        18353708 kB
Cached:         35536088 kB
SwapCached:        47708 kB
Active:         28975120 kB
Inactive:       27143572 kB
Active(anon):    1514004 kB
Inactive(anon):   765492 kB
Active(file):   27461116 kB
Inactive(file): 26378080 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      33554424 kB
SwapFree:       32550900 kB
Dirty:             15792 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2192080 kB
Mapped:            73996 kB
Shmem:             50516 kB
Slab:            8880128 kB
SReclaimable:    8392424 kB
SUnreclaim:       487704 kB
KernelStack:        8376 kB
PageTables:       139560 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    66515828 kB
Committed_AS:    6578468 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      393776 kB
VmallocChunk:   34325005944 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    167936 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        5056 kB
DirectMap2M:     2045952 kB
DirectMap1G:    65011712 kB
```

`slabtop -sc`:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 24709382 / 28507117 (86.7%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 2211714 / 2211815 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 107 / 183 (58.5%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 8026764.94K / 8620046.54K (93.1%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.02K / 0.30K / 4096.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
5479168 5196414  94%    0.99K 1369792        4   5479168K ext4_inode_cache
6662980 6648409  99%    0.19K 333149       20   1332596K dentry
11147878 9956546  89%    0.10K 301294       37   1205176K buffer_head
626199 573720  91%    0.55K  89457        7    357828K radix_tree_node
3458639 1395404  40%    0.06K  58621       59    234484K size-64
309529 278095  89%    0.20K  16291       19     65164K vm_area_struct
 94365  83090  88%    0.25K   6291       15     25164K tw_sock_TCP
 74940  65974  88%    0.30K   6245       12     24980K nf_conntrack_ffffffff81b18540
  8668   8054  92%    1.69K   2167        4     17336K TCP
 98520  87434  88%    0.12K   3284       30     13136K size-128
   182    182 100%   32.12K    182        1     11648K kmem_cache
 10132   9261  91%    1.00K   2533        4     10132K size-1024
 49120  48320  98%    0.19K   2456       20      9824K size-192
157003 116353  74%    0.05K   2039       77      8156K anon_vma_chain
 10170   9082  89%    0.69K   2034        5      8136K sock_inode_cache
 20090  13010  64%    0.38K   2009       10      8036K ip_dst_cache
 28620  18268  63%    0.19K   1431       20      5724K filp
  5856   5069  86%    0.64K    976        6      3904K proc_inode_cache
   918    911  99%    4.00K    918        1      3672K size-4096
 76176  45154  59%    0.04K    828       92      3312K anon_vma
  4055   3986  98%    0.77K    811        5      3244K shmem_inode_cache
  4686   4500  96%    0.58K    781        6      3124K inode_cache
 20979  20965  99%    0.14K    777       27      3108K sysfs_dir_cache
  1155   1053  91%    2.59K    385        3      3080K task_struct
  5082   4059  79%    0.50K    726        7      2904K skbuff_fclone_cache
  1396   1331  95%    2.00K    698        2      2792K size-2048
  1029    927  90%    2.06K    343        3      2744K sighand_cache
    35     35 100%   64.00K     35        1      2240K size-65536
   139    108  77%   16.00K    139        1      2224K size-16384
  3760   3566  94%    0.50K    470        8      1880K size-512
  8660   4042  46%    0.19K    433       20      1732K cred_jar
 24898  22924  92%    0.06K    422       59      1688K tcp_bind_bucket
 12030   9242  76%    0.12K    401       30      1604K eventpoll_epi
   166    143  86%    8.00K    166        1      1328K size-8192
  1162    927  79%    1.06K    166        7      1328K signal_cache
 32592  28332  86%    0.03K    291      112      1164K size-32
  3945   2357  59%    0.25K    263       15      1052K skbuff_head_cache
   640    465  72%    1.38K    128        5      1024K mm_struct
   254    254 100%    4.00K    254        1      1016K names_cache
 12243   9382  76%    0.07K    231       53       924K eventpoll_pwq
     7      7 100%  128.00K      7        1       896K size-131072
   990    563  56%    0.81K    110        9       880K task_xstate
  9858   9061  91%    0.07K    186       53       744K selinux_inode_security
   836    496  59%    0.69K     76       11       608K files_cache
   594    453  76%    0.81K     66        9       528K UDP
....
```

`iostat -x -m 10`:

```
Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 ([HOSTNAME REMOVED])  11/25/2015      _x86_64_        (32 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          29.29    0.04    5.51    1.52    0.00   63.64

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00    43.76     0.00    5.52   5.05   0.00
sdb              57.38   377.29  113.86   91.39     2.82     1.83    46.36     0.04    0.19   0.10   1.99

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          44.62    0.00    8.82    0.59    0.00   45.98

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               3.50   664.60    8.10  174.90     0.14     3.28    38.28     2.70   14.78   1.37  25.09

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          34.30    0.00    8.37    0.14    0.00   57.19

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.10   377.70    8.90   48.60     0.21     1.67    66.71     0.24    4.21   2.19  12.62
```

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Memory_Usage_and_Page_Cache.html Buffers == filesystem metadata, Cache == Data from/to files or devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffers field of free is representing all the I/O directly to block devices on your host, either via direct-IO or via filesystem metadata blocks ex: find etc.
You can find more info on which devices using these pages look at my blog page [here](https://vcheru.blogspot.ca/2015/11/linux-memory-what-are-those-buffers.html)

slabtop is representing separate cache area used by kernel and it's allocated for frequently used kernel objects. Looking at your slabinfo output, there is about ~7GB of ext4 inode and dentry cache. I suspect their corresponding disk blocks must be the one's showing up in 'Buffers' field

Comment: I'm marking this one as the answer because it points out important details: (1) The breakdown of what "filesystem metadata" is specifically -- direct IO AND filesystem metadata blocks; (2) that slab is separate from buffers and cache; (3) that entries for inode/dentry that are in slabs will have corresponding disk blocks in as part of buffer. For more details on slab being separate from buffers/cache see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5467207/4481063