# The reason why buffers in "free -h" command output is increased

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, free

I did two experiments.

**The first experiment (Ubuntu 20.04, ext4 filesystem):**

1. Run command `free -h -w`:

```
$ free -h -w
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           30Gi       2,6Gi        25Gi       106Mi       126Mi       2,1Gi        27Gi
```

2. Run command `sudo find / | grep something`
3. Run command `free -h -w` again and observe significant (about 1G) increasing of "buffers" column, and increasing of "cache" column as well (about 500M):

```
$ free -h -w
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           30Gi       2,6Gi        24Gi       106Mi       1,2Gi       2,6Gi        27Gi
```

**The second experiment (same PC):**

1. Run command `free -h -w`:

```
$ free -h -w
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           30Gi       2,6Gi        24Gi       106Mi       1,2Gi       2,6Gi        27Gi
```

2. Run command `dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p2 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=500` - your disk would be another here
3. Run command `free -h -w` again and observe 500M increasing of buffers:

```
$ free -h -w
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           30Gi       2,6Gi        24Gi       115Mi       1,7Gi       2,6Gi        27Gi
```

So the question is: why `buffers` column was increased in the first and why in the second case? I've read this [What is the buffers column in the output from free?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34422/what-is-the-buffers-column-in-the-output-from-free) but answers here are not appropriate for me.

They tell "buffers column contains metadata about files" - but it is wrong, because it is the "cache" column that counts slabs for inode, dentry and buffer_head (which are actually metadata of files). `man free` also tells us that `cache` column contains `SReclaimable`.

They also tell "buffers column contains cache of blocks from block devices" - and it looks more like the truth, it explains why `buffers` increased when I ran `dd`, but it does not explain why `buffers` column increased when I ran `find` command. And even in case of `dd` - why we need it if we already have file cache? Nobody read/write directly from/to block devices except of DVD disks.

Comment: But note that the "available" didn't change. When you no longer need the buffer data, you can just leave it there. The unneeded data can be "instantly" thrown away if you start to run low on space.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [How to identify cause of large buffer memory usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245532/how-to-identify-cause-of-large-buffer-memory-usage)
Seems that Linux stores files' inodes twice: first time as `ext4_inode_cache`/`inode_cache` in slabs (I observed  increasing of sizes of these slabs with `slabtop` command) and second time in buffers (because inodes are directly read from block devices, and all blocks which were directly read from block devices are stored in buffers).
So when I run `find` command, then linux reads inodes' blocks from block device, saves them in buffers and then creates inodes' cache in slabs. In result, both `cache` and `buffers` columns in `free` output are increased.